# List elements not nesting after using itertools combinations function?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am admittedly an extremely inexperienced programmer, who has been given the task of creating a Python program that will sort students into hotel rooms based on four choices of other students that they make (3 students they would like to . I am using a very elementary approach, seeing as I do not have the time nor abilities to create more advanced code.
This is certainly a question that is coming from a beginner, but I have been trying to use the itertools.combinations() function to create a list of all possible student groups of length 4. To execute the following steps of my program, I need each of these lists of 4 students (each group) to be inside a larger list. Everything I have tried so far is not working, and my plan for the following code is reliant on creating a nested list of groups of 4.

```
for comb in itertools.combinations(names, 4):
    combs = []
    for list in comb:
       combs.append(list)
    print(combs)
```

Above is one of my closest attempts to creating my desired list, but the output is as such:

```
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Lauryn']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Katelynn']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Alondra']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Amber']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Diya']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Delilah']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Jazlyn']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Alexus']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Alissa']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Alma']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'India']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Kyla']
['Destinee', 'Dahlia', 'Rylie', 'Macy']
```

(and it continues like this for a while).
How can I place each of these individual lists in a larger one?

Comment: It is unclear to me what the desired result is meant to be.  Can you please be a little more clear?  An example of the desired output structure would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
large_list = []
for comb in itertools.combinations(names, 4):
    #combs = [] # this line is not needed
    #for list in comb:
       #combs.append(list) # neither is this one, if you print comb it is already a list
    large_list.append(comb)
    print(combs)

names = ['Peter', 'John', 'Angela', 'Jim', 'Derek', 'Gabriella']
combs = list(itertools.combinations(names, 4))
'''
combs :
[('Peter', 'John', 'Angela', 'Jim'),
 ('Peter', 'John', 'Angela', 'Derek'),
 ('Peter', 'John', 'Angela', 'Gabriella'),
 ('Peter', 'John', 'Jim', 'Derek'),
 ('Peter', 'John', 'Jim', 'Gabriella'),
 ('Peter', 'John', 'Derek', 'Gabriella'),
 ('Peter', 'Angela', 'Jim', 'Derek'),
 ('Peter', 'Angela', 'Jim', 'Gabriella'),
 ('Peter', 'Angela', 'Derek', 'Gabriella'),
 ('Peter', 'Jim', 'Derek', 'Gabriella'),
 ('John', 'Angela', 'Jim', 'Derek'),
 ('John', 'Angela', 'Jim', 'Gabriella'),
 ('John', 'Angela', 'Derek', 'Gabriella'),
 ('John', 'Jim', 'Derek', 'Gabriella'),
 ('Angela', 'Jim', 'Derek', 'Gabriella')]
```

Just add the combs list to the `large_list` and it will save all combinations.

Or you can use `list(itertools.combinations(names, 4))` which will also produce one large list.

*ps* never use `list` as variable name, `list` is a function in python.